# Is there data structure in Java that is like TreeSet but allows duplicates?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I want to keep the ordering and allow duplicates. Should I build one for myself? Or is there some way that I can tweak Comparator (which I think remove() and insert() are using the same)? Thanks.

I want remove() to be in O(log n) and add() to be O(log n) as well.

PriorityQueue is one way but its remove() method takes O(n). If possible, how could I tweak this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you see [`TreeBag`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/bag/TreeBag.html) of [Apache Commons-Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/userguide.html)? This use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to provide the data storage, which provides provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the `containsKey`, `get`, `put` and remove operations.

A `Bag` stores each object in the collection together with a count of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

[Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`TreeMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html), perhaps?  Unlike Apache Commons, [`TreeMultiset` and the other `Multiset`s](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) get along with generics and properly obey the `Collection` contract, which makes it somewhat friendlier to use.

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: TreeMultiset<V> behaves like a TreeMap<V, Integer>, so it allows duplicates by aggregating elements for which the compareTo method returns 0.

I believe the OP wants something more like a SortedList, for which Guava doesn't have anything ready as far as I know.